# LAN programming on VB 6

Tags: ms-access, vb6, network-programming

I need to create a simple LAN program in VB 6, the program will insert data in an ACCESS DATABASE. this database should be updated so each PC accessing the database have the updated database.

I know VB 6 but have no idea about network programming so looking for help.

**Edit:**

I'll use Access database not MS SQL Server, thats the main problem, and it will be helpful to give some working code to send data to another PC on the lan

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to know "network programming" per se. You want to research ADO (a.k.a. MDAC), preferably version 2.8. The ADO library allows you to connect to databases such as Access, from VB6.

Comment: ADO is part of the old MDAC, and is also part of DAC 6.0 and later on current systems. Programs referencing the old ADO 2.8 interfaces still work fine, though for use with Jet 4.0 nothing new was introduced since the ADO 2.6 interface. People get confused: there is only one ADODB library (msado15.dll) on any given system even though typelibs for earlier interfaces are normally present for compatibility.  Compiling against too high a version level just makes your programs incompatible with older systems.  Most people should target ADO 2.5 for use with Jet 4.0 databases.

Comment: If you are using ACE databases you may need ADO 2.8 however, depending on what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

That's not neccesary know about network. for example get an dataset or recordset it very easy

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim nRowsAffected As Long
Dim con As ADODB.Connection

con.ConnectionString = "server=mynetworksqlserver,user='viewuser',pwd='14aE%9¡3',defaultdatabase='users'"
con.CursorLocation = adUseClient
Set rs = con.Execute("select * from clients", nRowsAffected)
```

now the matter is learning curve and have well Desing it can take an long time. The point is gain experiencie and the time show to you the correct way (although if do too an bad it pass bill)